# the admin is not in the sudoers file

Tags: python, terminal, pip, sudo, sudoers

facing an error in installing pandas to import it in my python code

and trying to install it via many ways but it always ends with this message "username is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

even though I am the only user in this Mac and it's entitled with 'admin' in the user & group panel, and the box of "allow user to administer this computer" is checked.

Comment: If you don't actually show what you're attempting to do, we can't really help you.

Comment: But `pip install pandas` or `pip install pandas --user` should work. Or use a virtual environment, if that's your thing. That always avoids the administrator installation problem (for Python packages at least).

Comment: So is your question about installing Pandas, or about 'admin' not being in sudoers?

Comment: (pip install pandas) didn't work with me, so. I tried (sudo pip install) to instal pip (sudo pip3 install pandas) (conda install pandas)(apt-get install python3-pandas) but always give me this message "username is not in the sudoers file" after entering the password, so I'm trying to solve the admin not being shudders to solve the installation problem

Comment: [edit] your question to mention what you did; don't put it a comment.

Comment: Conda doesn't require root access. `pip(3)` with the --user option doesn't require root access. apt-get doesn't even work on Macos. And you don't mention what it means "didn't work with me": what is the error you got? A permission error? Something else?

Comment: But you're trying to solve one problem to solve another problem. Are you sure you don't just want to solve the installation problem instead? If you can stay away from the admin and root, that's recommended.